# GraphQL: Subscriptions vs periodic querying to be up to date without refresh?

Tags: websocket, tcp, graphql, refresh

Imagine that we want to serve a web application to thousands of users. The information on the page should stay up to date even if the user does not actively refresh the page. At the moment, we have two ways to achieve this:

- Setup subscriptions to the data that may change via GraphQL
- Setup periodic queries to GraphQL on a loaded page

Here are some thoughts:

- A change in the data should be visible to the client after maximum 30s. So periodic queries would need to run every 30s at least.
- Let's say 1000 users have our page open at the same time, even if they are not actively looking at it. If we query every 30s, that will generate a base load of 33.3 queries/second even if nobody actively requests a new view or refreshes.
- On the "worst" view, there are maybe 60 data points that would individually update via subscriptions. So 1000 open tabs would be 60k open subscriptions.

We are wondering which solution scales better / is recommended.

- Is it best to have thousands of subscriptions running (essentially thousands of open TCP sockets powering the websocket connections) or is it better to query again and again for barely changing data?
- How big is the "steady-state"/"heartbeat" load of the open websocket connections for the subscriptions?
- From a server perspective, will the open websockets or the periodic queries require more CPU load for the GraphQL server?

If you have experience with such a trade-off, it would be great if you could share it.

Answer (score 1):

A 30 second refresh time is not nearly long enough in my opinion for you to think that a websocket is necessary. Remember that websocket is going to be constantly pinging your server in order to keep itself online. If your SLA is 30 seconds, you're going to be pinging a lot more than that with a websocket.

The main feature of websockets is that you can publish to a user in basically real-time. It doesn't sound like your application actually needs real time interaction. For instance, a chat application is going to need the user to see constant updates. A user is going to expect their new message to appear virtually instantly after being sent, and in addition you may need to send activity indicators like a typing indicator,  online/offline status, and other real time indicators. It doesn't sound like your SLAs are anywhere near that level.

With that said though, a websocket can scale out to infinity. A single EC2 r5large instance can probably handle thousands (or maybe even tens of thousand) of websocket connections without a problem (depending of course on how much processing you will do on ping/pong).

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a cache with "popular" updates inside the web app. When some change is made, that you know that will be needed by the customers, you can generate the response only once and add it to the cache. The replies to customers would get the latest response from cache.

The trick is to figure out a system of keys to be shared with the client-side of the app. Instead clients asking for any "view" at any moment, they would be mapped to preset views at preset moments, that you would ensure that are pre-generated in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to query every 30 secs especially if your data doesn't change. I suggest implementing an observer pattern where you specify to the client which data has changed so you can select which queries to run. In case there are frequent data changes, add a debounce handler that queries the server every 30 secs regardless the number of notifications from the server.